# Is the browser's X-XSS-Protection/XSS Auditor sufficient to prevent XSS?

Tags: php, javascript, security, xss

As I understand it, I would need to disable X-XSS-Protection in the headers server-side in order to prevent XSS from occurring via a GET request.

For example, the user browses to

```
http://mysite.com/index.php?page=<script type='text/javascript'> alert("XSS"); </script>
```

Assuming that $_GET['page'] is echoed to the page from PHP without being altered in any way, the XSS Auditor should catch that there is stuff from the request being echoed to the page and put a stop to it.

Is this sufficient to prevent XSS attacks, or can this browser protection be bypassed by the attacker?

Sufficient meaning that it is supported by all major browsers and is not bypassable.

Answer (score 2):

No, not at all. Client-side XSS filtering is trying to solve a server-side problem (missing output escaping) at the client side, where there is not sufficient knowledge to solve the problem. It can never work 100% and it will always produce false positives. It is a defence-in-depth measure and a deeply questionable one. You **must not** rely on it alone as a solution to XSS.

Client-side XSS filtering:

- can't defend against multiple-reflected XSS (ie include `<` in one parameter and `script` in another parameter which gets output next to it);
- can't defend against application-specific encoding layers (eg submit in JSON format, decode and display without escaping);
- can't defend against types of input other than form parameters;
- can't defend against attacks based on inserting other content into the page than scripts;
- has a very patchy history of defending against obscure ways to inject script, like CSS;
- can't defend against stored XSS at all;
- isn't supported on all popular browsers;
- allows an attacker to selectively disable scripts on your page, sabotaging it.

This is not a win.

Answer (score 1):

I would NOT recommend depending on user's browser for any sort of protection as the version and type of browser is always unpredictable. Which means that you need to make sure that you are taking all the measures to prevent against XSS (or any other type of attack) at your server/application level.

Answer (score 1):

It might be enough to catch *reflected* XSS attacks, but there's no way it would prevent the even-more-harmful *persisted* XSS attacks. Additionally, not all browsers have XSS protection. Do you really want only *some* users to have protection *only* because you neglected to escape output? Escaping in the appropriate places will fix both types of XSS, even where the browser lacks XSS protection.